# Unit of Work, Entity Framework DBContext Scope

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I've run into a bit of a problem with EF looking for the best practice for this problem:

```
public void TestEntityFramework_UOWImplementation()
{
    using (UnitOfWorkInventory uow = new UnitOfWorkInventory())
    {
        IMaterialRepository repos = new MaterialRepository(uow);

        Material mat = GetMaterial("Mikes Material", 1);

        mat.CostPrice = 20;

        repos.InsertOrUpdate(mat);

        uow.Commit();
    }
}

private Material GetMaterial(string sku, int clientId)
{
    IMaterialRepository repos = new MaterialRepository(new UnitOfWorkInventory();

    return repos.Find(sku, clientId);

}
```

In the TestEntityFramework_UOWImplementation() method, its fine, i call create a scope for my unit of work.. and create a repository inside it.

But when i want to getMaterials() as below..  I have no access to the unit of work or the repository, unless i actually pass it as a parameter!  This is clearly not particularly nice.

How do people get around this problem??

Thanks in advance!

Neil

Comment: Shouldn't `GetMaterial` be an instance method in the `MaterialRepository` class?

Comment: thats a good point! :) but say there was some one off case where you would want to do a Where()..  i suppose these would also be in the repo.  Thanks! now that i see it written down its obvious :)

Comment: Actually, say there were several repo queries required. do you not think there would ever be a case where the querying would be done outside of the repo?

Or say i had some method called CalculateMaterialPrices() which needed a list of Materials to calculate.  Would you call the repo GetMaterials() method in the TestEntityFramework_UOWImplementation() method or in the CalculateMaterialPrices() method,  if the latter, how would you do access the repo?  or am i not on the right track here!

Comment: More frameworks these days expect to work with an `IQueryable<T>` - I'm thinking of things like Web API - so it can be useful to add a method to each repository that just returns one. This also satisfies use cases such as you describe, where you want to specify the query outside the repo. Whether or not this breaks encapsulation is debatable, but it gets the job done!

Comment: its a workaround alright, but definately not a good solution.  Is there no way around this?

Comment: It's an architecture decision. If you're writing a noddy site, it's ok to expose your `DbContext`. If you're writing a medium business site, it's probably ok to expose `IQueryable`. If you're writing War And Peace, you probably want to use Domain Driven Design. Also, you can have different strategies for reading and writing data - exposing `IQueryable` makes reading data easy, but you can still lock down writes.

Comment: Yeah i see what you mean, but if it doesnt break encapsulation, it definately brakes the UOW.  Do you thinnk the following solution would work:
In your UOW, make the objectContext [ThreadStatic],  then in each repository have the constructor:<br/>
`public class MyRepo : GenericRepo 
{
         public MyRepo(DbContext container)
            : base(new RepositorySession(container))
        { }
}`

Comment: This is a big topic - I think you'd be better off on [`programmers`](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) - I would ask again there.

Comment: sorry i mean the constructor would be like :     
         public MaterialRepository_Refactor()
            : base(RepositorySession.Current)
        {  }     where current is the ThreadStatic UOW

Comment: ok - ill put it to them, but the more i think about it, i think what i mentioned above is a good idea.  Because on the dispose of the uow.  The threadstatic Context can be set to null, ensuring the UOW is kept intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone was looking for a way around this, I done something a bit different.

I used a Dependency Injection framework (StructureMap) to handle all DI, so everytime i instantiate a repository it will retrieve the DBContext from the Service Locator of StructureMap.  I also make the dbcontext scope to be for the duration of the request from the webserver.

The advantage here being that everytime i retrieve or inject a DBContext, it will retrieve the same context for the duration of the request meaning i can use this across multiple methods and class!  I pass the interface type as a generic param to the constructor, meaning that i can point the repo as different contexts.  Helpful in applications where there are lots of dbcontexts.

Repo Constructor Eg:

```
public class PurchaseOrderRepository<TDbContext> : GenericRepository<PurchaseOrder>, IPurchaseOrderRepository<TDbContext> where TDbContext : DbContext
{

        public PurchaseOrderRepository()
            : base((TDbContext)ObjectFactory.GetInstance<TDbContext>())
        {
        }
}
```

Usage:

```
 //resolves the request scope InventoryContext... 
var pRepos = new PurchaseOrderRepository<IInventoryContext>();
```

and the structure map dependency looks like:

```
    For<IInventoryContext>().HttpContextScoped().Use<InventoryContext>();
```

Comment: im interested in opinions!!

Answer (score 3):

In your implementation you wont have access to the Unit of Work like that.  What I do is use an IoC container and Dependency Injection to handle it.  I have a WCF service that uses Unit of Work with a repository pattern against EF5.

You can read more about repository pattern, unit of work, and EF [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/JuansAndZeros/archive/2012/10/03/building-a-repository-pattern-against-ef-5-model-first.aspx) but basically what I do is in the constructor of my service class I inject the Unit of Work like so:

```
    private readonly IUnitOfWork uow;

    public LoanService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        uow = unitOfWork;
    }
```

Then I can use uow.WhateverMethod in my repos anywhere in the service.  I use [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) to handle the injection of IUnitOfWork.    Hope it helps you.